# How to mount a single file with `docker run`?

Tags: docker, nginx

In docker-compose, this works fine:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - web_server/local-nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

However, if I try to do the same thing using `docker run` directly:

```
$ docker run --network host -p 8080:8080 \
  -v "web_server/local-nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" \
  nginx:latest
```

I get errors:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create web_server/local-nginx.conf: "web_server/local-nginx.conf"
includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. 
If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
```

I also tried using `--mount`, with the same results:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 --network host \
  --mount src="web_server/local-nginx.conf",dst="/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" \
  nginx:latest
```

Comment: This can be closed, as it was caused by a typo (when trying to supply an absolute path, as the error suggested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-hand side of the `docker run -v` option must be a volume name or an absolute path.  Docker Compose understands relative paths in `volumes:`, but plain Docker doesn't.

You need to include the current directory name in the option.  Using the `$PWD` environment variable for this is common:

```sh
docker run ... \
  -v "$PWD/web_server/local-nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" \
  ...
```

Comment: Well.. I thought I had tried that - as it's what the error says, but I must have made a typo.